# Copy Chart with DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I read a .xlsx file and I want to copy a chart from one sheet to another. How can I do that?
Here is a sample code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
{
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = ExcelExportHelper.GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Sheet1");
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = ExcelExportHelper.GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Sheet2");

    // I see that the charts are here, but I don't know how to copy them to the other sheet;
    ChartPart chartPart3 = worksheetPart1.DrawingsPart.ChartParts.ToList()[0];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this line: `workdheetPart2.DrawingPart.ChartParts.Add(chartPart3);`?

Comment: @RobJarvis workdheetPart2.DrawingPart.ChartParts returns IEnumerable and I can't add this way.